# error printing Integer with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner with python trying to write this but not working. Any help?

```
CP=input("enter the cost price: ")
SP=input("enter the sale price: ")
if (SP>CP):
    print ("Congratulations !! you made a profit of ", + SP-CP) 
    print("Congratulations!! you made a profit of %f" % SP-CP)
elif (CP>SP):
    print("you are in loss of %f" % CP-SP)
else:
    print("you got nothing")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 3 (which I'm assuming you are using because of the `python-3.x` tag you included), the `input` function returns a string, and you can't do math on a string. You will need to change

```
CP=input("enter the cost price: ")
SP=input("enter the sale price: ")
```

to

```
CP = int( input("enter the cost price: ") )
SP = int( input("enter the sale price: ") )
```

(spaces added to show what I changed).

As the answer above said, you will also need to add parenthesis around your substitution values so

```
print("Congratulations!! you made a profit of %f" % SP-CP)
```

becomes

```
print("Congratulations!! you made a profit of %f" % (SP-CP) )
```

(Edit: Benjamin beat me by 3 seconds!)

Comment: Aha, sorry dude. Like the fact you've detailed what you changed, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

You need to put brackets around `SP-CP` and `CP-SP`.

**Explanation**

The string formatting operator `%` is evaluated first and you can't subtract a number from a string.

It's like you are writing

```py
print(("Congratulations!! you made a profit of %f" % SP)-CP)
```

But what you want is

```
print("Congratulations!! you made a profit of %f" % (SP-CP))
```

**Further reading**

You find the operator precedence (which operator is evaluated first) [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). See footnote [8](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id27): The string formatting operator `%` has the same precedence like the modulo operator `%`.

Answer (score 0):

The input built-in returns a string. You will need to cast it to a float like below. Assuming of course, a float is what you wanted. You can do the same with an integer, using int().

```
CP=float(input("enter the cost price: "))
SP=float(input("enter the sale price: "))
if (SP>CP): 
    print("Congratulations!! you made a profit of %f" % (SP-CP))
elif (CP>SP):
    print("you are in loss of %f" % (CP-SP))
else:
    print("you got nothing")
```